# How to implement random sampling with continuous variables?

Tags: algorithms, probability-theory, randomness, sampling, books

How functions like rnorm in R (and similar functions) create a random sample ? If I want to implement one algorithm to simulate this procedure what can I do? When you have the pdf or pmf of a distribution how can you use this to create a random sample with a computer? Is there some book on this topic?Is this a numerical analysis topic? I searched alot but I couldn't find any information about this.

Comment: If you can sample a $U(0,1)$ random variable, apply the inverse CDF of a random variable to get a sample of it. For Gaussians there are other options, see for example [this question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/16334/how-to-sample-from-a-normal-distribution-with-known-mean-and-variance-using-a-co).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One standard approach is to use [inverse transform sampling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_transform_sampling): if $F$ is the cdf of the desired random variable and $U$ is uniformly distributed, then $F^{-1}(U)$ has the desired distribution.  There are more sophisticated methods for specific distributions; you can find references and links where you can learn more in the linked Wikipedia article.